# Modificar el estado de una variable booleana al hacer click

Tags: python

Quiero que al hacer click cambiar el estado de "buscar" de `false` a `true` y no lo consigo puesto que ahora las variables "buscar" (si no me equivoco) son independientes.

Las dos opciones que creo son la solución sería o hacer "buscar" global o mediante POO. Tengo entendido que hay que evitar el uso de globales para así evitar errores pero por ahora la POO aun no la domino.

¿Podeis ayudarme a pasar esta a global (se que es fácil pero no me sale)? Y mientras yo seguiré aprendiendo POO y cuando pueda la modifico.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2


def main():

    buscar = False

    while(True):

        cv2.namedWindow('ventana')
        cv2.setMouseCallback('ventana',buscar_circulos)

        while buscar == True:
            print('101 El estado de buscar es ',buscar)

        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break

    cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()


def buscar_circulos(event,x,y,flags,param):
    if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONUP:
        buscar = True
        print('100 El estado de buscar es ',buscar)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Salud

Comment: Hola NEA, el problema es idéntico al de tu pregunta anterior, usa `global buscar` en las funciones y define `buscar` a nivel de módulo, `buscar = False` debajo de los imports.

Comment: Hola @FJSevilla, disculpa se que es lo mismo, pero no me termino de aclarar. Y en el anterior, porque no tuve que declarar un global grayFrame en la función buscar_circulos?

Comment: Porque no reasignabas un nuevo "valor
" a la variable en ningún momento como haces aquí (`buscar = True`). **Puedes acceder a variables globales desde una función sin el uso de `global`, lo que no puedes hacer es asignar un nuevo objeto a la variable** . En este caso se crea una variable local a la función que solapa a la global y desde ese momento la función usa la local. Esto se diseñó así por seguridad, para evitar que una función modificara una variable global por error. De todas formas recomiendo usar `global` siempre que se use una variable global aunque no se reasigne a la variable.

Comment: Cuando desde una función se hace referencia a una variable el intérprete busca primero en las variables locales a dicha función, si no está definida busca en el espacio global. Ahora bien, cuando se produce una asignación siempre se usa o crea una variable local a no ser que se use `global` para indicar lo contrario de forma explícita. Como comento arriba esto es una decisión de diseño para intentar hacer más seguras las variables globales, forzando a que se use `global variable` explícitamente se evita que se modifique una variable global sin querer por haber usado el mismo nombre.

Comment: Aquí tienes como quedaría tu código: https://repl.it/repls/ElaborateWoozyIde La pregunta realmente es ahora mismo un duplicado exacto y la voy a marcar como tal, pero no dudes nunca en preguntar estas cuestiones a quién responde tu pregunta, tu duda es totalmente comprensible. Un saludo.